# using break point in xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I followed http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions this link to set up break point in my app,but still it shows me thread and process, I can not find the exact line of code where exception arises.I am using xcode 4.5 and my device is having ios5.0,Please help me out. /Users/administrator/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-01-17 at 12.33.42 PM.png

Comment: Is it possible to add a screenshot of those threads and processes screen?

Comment: breakpoint just breaks the execution if the code is executing that part of the code. but if you want to find where the exception is coming from, use all exceptions.. it will throw the exception accordingly...

Comment: Sorry I am not allowed to post screenshot as I am a new user

Comment: I have used all exception,but still it shows me EXC_BAD_ACCESS and show the Thread and process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the breakpoint navigator at the bottom hit + and select exception breakpoint. This will pause the program at the line of code that crashes

Comment: Yes it does at this piece of code: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MapAppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: can you put in some stack trace?